# Simple git: Not finished with issue for commit, but working on a diff computer. Which option is better in practice?

Tags: git

Say I'm not finished with an issue and need to switch to another computer. Which of these methods, that both work, is better in practice? Amend or reset?

A commit, then on the new computer:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

or a commit, then later when the issue is fixed:

```
git commit --amend
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both do the same thing, as far as I'm aware.
Using the `--amend` route means it's easier to access your temporary commit (if for example, you irreparably broke something on the new computer). However, that commit is still accessible via `reflog` even if you do reset.

Both approaches will give you the exact same result, so it's really a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

Neither, just check it in and push up and then on other computer pull it down and continue your work on your branch.